# Java string replaceAll method

Tags: java, string, replace

hi i want to use Java string replaceAll() method to replace "x3" with "multiplied by 3" in my text file. But there is a string occurence "xxx3" which i do not want to replace. how can I do it

Example :

```
        ACTUAL                                     DESIRED  
1)ENGAGE XX3 COLOGNE 165ML          ENGAGE XX3 COLOGNE 165ML
2)FDW MEN REFRESHING PULSE 125GMSX3   FDW MEN REFRESHING PULSE 125GMS multuiplied by 3
```

Comment: Make use of regular expression

Comment: You can try a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind).

Comment: Show us sample input and output

Comment: 1)ENGAGE XX3 COLOGNE 165ML, here it should not replace
2)FDW MEN REFRESHING PULSE 125GMSX3, here it should replace

Comment: try string tokenizer then apply replace function.

Comment: @sujit, what about FDW MEN REFRESHING PULSE 125GMSXX3?

Comment: it should replace x3 in any case unless it is xx3

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
StringName.replaceAll("(?<!x)x3", "multiplied by 3");
```

`replaceAll` method uses a regex as first argument, this pattern has two parts :

`"x3"` : each time the method finds "x3" in your string, there is a chance to match the pattern

`"(?<!x)"` is a negative lookbehind. That means : "If my current part of the string is precedeed by x, the pattern will not match, else it will"

e.g. : `"(?<!example)x3"` will match each `"x3"` in your string, except any `"examplex3"`

Hope it helped you

Comment: looking at your example, i am not sure what prefix should be ignored. Do you want to ignore XX3 or XXX3, or both ?

Comment: it should ignore only "xx3" but can u explain ur code please